# Optional @Path params in Retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I'm looking for a way to make optional @Path params.
Let's say we have following api method:

*/brand/{brand_id}/product/{type}*

***brand_id*** and **type** are optional, so these requests will be valid:

- /brand/{brand_id}/product/{type}
- /brand/product/{type}
- /brand/{brand_id}/product/
- /brand/product/

I don't want to define 4 separate methods in my interface, because they do same job.

I hope my question is clear.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression in your path, like this:

```
@Path("/brand")
public interface MyClass{

    @Get
    @Path("{brand_Id: .*}/product/{type: .*}")
    public Response doSomething();

}
```

In this case, the path will support this urls:

```
brand/product/
brand/product/{type}
brand/{brand_id}/product/
brand/{brand_id}/product/{type}
```

Take a look to this [link](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.0.2.GA/userguide/html_single/index.html#_Path_and_regular_expression_mappings)

Comment: This would allow things liked brand/x/y/z/product/ as well if I am not wrong